# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I get this error in my crash report but cannot figure out what it means. I think its because I'm saying to return -1 if my cursor is null. Which would cause the crash. But I'm not sure why my cursor would be null? This method in my DB class gets called in the onResume of one of my activities. Would it be better to call it in the onCreate (that way its only called once)?

```
public int getLastId() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LEVEL, KEY_MONEY, KEY_DAYSLEFT, KEY_VOTES, KEY_CORRUPTION};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null , null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToLast();
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            return id;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Would this code be better?

```
public int getLastId() throws SQLException{
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LEVEL, KEY_MONEY, KEY_DAYSLEFT, KEY_VOTES, KEY_CORRUPTION};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,null , null, null, null, null);

        if(c != null){
            c.moveToLast();
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            return id;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an empty cursor. Therefore also check cursor count.i.e. change

```
  if(c != null){
            c.moveToLast();
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            return id;
        }
```

to

```
 if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0){
            c.moveToLast();
            int id = c.getInt(0);
            return id;
        }
```

Comment: I will try that. should i still leave the default as return -1?

Comment: @user3812501 it depends what you want if table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably being raised by the `moveToLast()` call, and you are getting it because your `Cursor` has no rows, presumably because your table is empty.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, but the table is not empty as this does not happen all the time only sometimes. would the edited code above be better?

Comment: @user3812501: "but the table is not empty" -- since you are not checking the count of returned rows, I fail to see how you know that the table is not empty.

Comment: good point, my guess that its not empty is because this call works most of the time (there is only one table in that database, created well before that call is made)